# Ajuda com upload e visualização de imagem com $_SESSION ou $_COOKIE

Tags: php, mysql

Estou precisando fazer, com que o usuário troque a imagem sem alterar o arquivo de origem do Banco de Dados, ou seja, quando ele encerrar o BROWSER depois de ter efetuado a troca, ele ou qualquer outro usuário entrando novamente no Site, encontrará a mesma imagem de inicio, pois ela esta armazenada no BD.

E para isso andei pesquisando, mas não entendendo o raciocínio, e vi que usando $_SESSION ou mesmo $_COOKIE eu poderia ter o resultado desejado, o usuário troca a imagem por outra vindo de seu próprio computador, e essa imagem ser armazenada em uma SESSION ou mesmo como um COOKIE. Mas não estou sabendo criar o código para realizar tal tarefa por não enter o raciocínio dos tutoriais que analisei, que me deixou com as seguintes duvidas:

Qual seria a pasta de destino das imagens?

Como manter o nome de origem da imagem ao fazer o upload da mesma?

Pois o upload que uso (postado mais abaixo), altera o nome de origem dos arquivos, para não haver duplicidades dos mesmos, usando o rand() para isso.

Tem como os amigos me mostrarem como devo construir o código com a SESSION ou COOKIE, baseado no exemplo do endereço http://www.efacilfacil.com/?

Código da Página edit_logo-upd.php:

```
<?php
include 'cabecalho.php';

$logo = $_POST['logo'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

<div align="center"  style="margin: 0 0 0 180px; max-width:1000px;">

<?php
$codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho WHERE codigo = '$codigo'");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

            $pasta = '../upload/';

            if (isset($_POST['logo'])){
            $check = @$_POST['apagar'];
            foreach($check as $logo){
            $delcheck = mysql_query("UPDATE pagcabecalho SET logo='' WHERE codigo = '$codigo'") or die (mysql_error()); 
            unlink($pasta.'/'.$logo);
            if ($delcheck >= '1'){
            echo 'Imagem deletada com sucesso!';
            }else{
            echo 'Erro ao deletar imagem, tente novamente!';
            }
            }
            }
?>

<?php include 'upload_logo.php'; ?>
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <?php
            include '../conexao.php';
            $seleciona = "SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho";
            $queryum = mysql_query($seleciona);
            while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($queryum)){
            $logo = $list['logo'];
            ?>
        <input size="1" type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $codigo;?>" readonly>
        <input type="hidden" type="checkbox" name="apagar[]" value="<?php echo $logo;?>" checked readonly>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

        <label><h4>Selecione uma nova imagem como Logo:</h4></label><br />
        <input type="file" name="logo[]" accept="image/*" ><br />
        <input type="submit" name="logo" value="Atualizar">
        </form>
</div>
```

Código da Página upload_logo.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['logo'])){

//INFO IMAGEM   
$file = $_FILES['logo'];
$numFile = count(array_filter($file['name']));

//PASTA
$folder = '../upload';

//REQUiSITOS
$permite = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
$maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

//MENSAGEM
$msg = array();
$errorMsg = array(
    1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o Limite de finido em upload_maxsize',
    2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em Max_file_size',
    3 => 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
    4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo',
);

if($numFile <= 0)
    echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!!';
else{
    for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
        $name = $file['name'][$i];
        $type = $file['type'][$i];
        $size = $file['size'][$i];
        $error = $file['error'][$i];
        $tmp = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

        $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
        $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

        if($error != 0)
            $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
        else if (!in_array($type, $permite))
            $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
        else if($size > $maxSize)
            $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB!";

        else{
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder."/".$novoNome))             
        $logo = $_FILES['logo'];

            $update = mysql_query("UPDATE pagcabecalho SET logo = '$novoNome' WHERE codigo = '$codigo'");

        if($update == ''){

echo "<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('Erro ao atualizar Imagem!!!');
</script>";
}else{
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= ../admin/interna.php'>
<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('Imagem atualizada com sucesso!');
</script>";
}}}}}
?>
```

Desde já meus agradecimentos pela a atenção a minha dúvida, e abraços à todos.

Answer (score 1):

Não é bom você armazenar uma imagem inteira numa $_SESSION. Faça o upload da imagem em um diretório e depois salve na $_SESSION o nome do arquivo. Aqui vai um exemplo.

```
<?php
//session_set_cookie_params( 0 ); // Se quiser encerrar a SESSION quando o browser fechar, descomente essa função.
@session_start(); // Inicia a session.
if( isset( $_POST['logo'] ) ){
    //INFO IMAGEM   
    $file = $_FILES['logo'];
    $numFile = count( array_filter( $file['name'] ) );

    //PASTA
    $folder = '../upload';

    //REQUiSITOS
    $permite = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif' );
    $maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

    //MENSAGEM
    $msg = array();
    $errorMsg = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o Limite de finido em upload_maxsize',
        2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em Max_file_size',
        3 => 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
        4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo',
    );

    if( $numFile <= 0 )
    {
        echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!!';
    }
    else
    {
        for( $i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++ ){
            $name = $file['name'][$i];
            $type = $file['type'][$i];
            $size = $file['size'][$i];
            $error = $file['error'][$i];
            $tmp = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

            $extensao = @end( explode( '.', $name ) );
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

            //Se você quer várias mensagens não use else.
            if( $error != 0 )
            {
                $msg[] = "Erro: {$errorMsg[$error]}! Nome do arquivo: {$name}.";
            }
            if ( !in_array( $type, $permite ) )
            {
                $msg[] = "Tipo do arquivo inválido! Nome do arquivo: {$name}.";
            }
            if( $size > $maxSize )
            {
                $msg[] = "Tamanho do arquivo muito grande! Nome do arquivo: {$name}.";
            }
            else{
                $destino = $folder."/".$novoNome;
                if( move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $destino ) )
                {
                    $_SESSION['logo'] = $destino;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Erro ao salvar arquivo!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para mostrar a imagem:

```
<img src="<?=$_SESSION['logo']?>" />
```

É bom saber que as funções mysql_* estão obsoletas e vão ser deletadas em versões futuras do PHP. Dê uma olhada em [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) ou [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli.php). Em todas as páginas que você usar $_SESSION você deve incluir session_start().

Comment: Valeu João, obrigadão pelo exemplo, vou dar uma olhada com muita atenção para aprender um pouco sobre SESSION. E valeu pela dica sobre o MYSQL.

Comment: João, acabei de testar seu exemplo, e quase funcionou do jeito que preciso. Ao trocar a imagem ele altera  o BD retirando o nome do arquivo referente ao logo, e eu tenho que estar atualizando a pagina 'edit_logo-upd.php' para que a nova imagem apareça, e na página principal do Site ele nem atualizando aparece, nem a atualizada e nem a anterior, pois ele retira do BD. Estou deixando o endereço (http://www.efacilfacil.com/) para que vc. possa ver o que esta acontecendo, valeu? Mas já me deu uma luz, brigadão.

Comment: **PS.**  Na página principal também inseri alinha da imagem dessa forma: `<img width="150" src="<?=$_SESSION['logo']?>" />`, esta correto?

Comment: Sim, precisa. Colocou o session_start no início da página principal?

Comment: Olá João, cara deve ter sido o sono ou mesmo a falta de atenção, e acredito que tenha sida a segunda hipótese, pois o problema estava na falta do `session_start()` nas outras páginas. Agora esta funcionando... Endereço de acesso (http://www.efacilfacil.com/). Mas me deparei com duas situações. **Primeiro**, os aquivos ficam armazenados na pasta upload no servidor, e isso poderá acarretar uma sobre carga de espaço, por imagens que não estarão sendo usadas, pois seria um simulador. Tem como direcionar para uma pasta tipo a **C:\TEMP/** do próprio usuário?

Comment: A **Segunda** duvida é como posso manter a imagem do Banco de Dados ao entrar na página? Ou seja, teria como trabalhar com os dois PHP's, o `<img width="150" src="upload/<?php echo $res['logo']; ?>" />` que traz o arquivo do BD, e somente quando o usuário enviar uma nova imagem seria trocado pelo o `<img width="150" src="<?=$_SESSION['logo']?>" />` que pega o arquivo da `$_SESSION`!!! Sei que estou abusando, mas tem como você me dar mais essa luz... Desde já agradecendo, pois ajudou muito a sua orientação, BRIDADÃO MESMO.

Comment: No caso de você armazenar a imagem client side acho que não é possível com PHP, e também não é recomendado, porque nunca se deve confiar na entrada do usuário. No caso de usar dois recursos, banco de dados e session, você pode usar if ou ternário: `<?=(isset($_SESSION['logo']))?$_SESSION['logo']:$res['logo']?>` Esse código verifica se o $_SESSION['logo'] existe, se existir ele chama o SESSION, se não ele chama o $res.